# Footnotes in custom fields

Tags: custom-field, filters, post-meta

I am using Jquery Hover Footnotes plugin that allows adding footnotes and dynamically displays them on hover-over.

In other words, I use `{{FOOTNOTE_NUMBER}}`,  Then I embrace the actual footnote text with double brackets `[[FOOTNOTE_NUMBER]] Footnote text [[FOOTNOTE_NUMBER]]`. the plugin will find these "shortcodes" and auto place a box onhover on a footnote. For more information about this plugin thanks to visit http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-hover-footnotes/

An example here:
http://restoredisrael.org/blog/961/footnote-plugin-test-page/

I am in addition  using custom fields , and I get their content by using:

```
echo get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

The problem is that this plugin is only applied to the content (returned by `the_content()`). 
While looking at the plugin code, I found:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'jqFootnotes', 1, 1);
```

So I tried adding this filter also for the meta values:

```
add_filter('get_post_meta', 'jqFootnotes', 1, 1);
add_filter('key_name', 'jqFootnotes', 1, 1);
```

BUT IN VAIN.

What should I do so that the plugin will be applied also on footnotes inside my custom fields?

Comment: That plugin has not been updated in over two years. You should use with caution. How does that plugin work? Ho do you add footnotes to content?

Comment: "More information" is all the thanks I need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need to do is find where your custom meta data is displayed and do this:

```
echo jqFootnotes(get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single));
```

That will run the `jqFootnotes` filter on your post meta, and I think that will do what you need (assuming that `$post_id`, `$key`, and `$single` are set appropriately)..

**Side note:** just because there is a `the_content()` function and a `the_content` filter doesn't mean that you can use any function name as a filter. Most functions do not have a matching filter.

For reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

Comment: I tried this solution but it is not working even if it is very logical. Should I perhaps add the filter somewhere before applying it? Anyway thank you for your time and for the interesting side note.

Comment: See my edit. Skip any attempt at using filters.

Comment: it is working, real sincere thanks. :-). I hope I can me too provide with such good quality help in this community

Comment: now I have enought repu to vote :-)